# Data type mismatch when passing function to function within class

Tags: c++, types

I am trying to implement a websocket inside of a class with a library for arduino
(https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets/blob/master/src/WebSocketsClient.h) on an esp8266s. 
 I am not using the Arduino IDE but the ESPHome integration of Home-assistant which is why the code has to be inside of a class. 
To implement the websocket I have to pass a function to another function but apparently there is a mismatch of data types and I don't understand how to accomplish this. Here is a shortened version of my code:
**My code:**

```
#include "esphome.h"
#include "WebSocketsClient.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class CustomWebsocket : public Component, public Sensor {
    public:
        WebSocketsClient webSocket;

        CustomWebsocket();
        void webSocketEventCustom(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length);
        void setup() override;
};

void CustomWebsocket::webSocketEventCustom(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {

    switch(type) {
        case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
            break;
        case WStype_CONNECTED: 
            break;
        case WStype_TEXT:
            //do stuff
            break;
    };
};

void CustomWebsocket::setup(){
    webSocket.begin("192.168.178.23", 81, "/");
    webSocket.onEvent(this->webSocketEventCustom);
};
```

The last line is where the function is passed. It results in this error message:

**Error Message:**

```
error: no matching function for call to 'WebSocketsClient::onEvent(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
  webSocket.onEvent(this->webSocketEventCustom);
                                              ^
note: candidate is:
In file included from src/CustomWebsocket.h:2:0,
                 from src/main.cpp:43:
note: void WebSocketsClient::onEvent(WebSocketsClient::WebSocketClientEvent)
     void onEvent(WebSocketClientEvent cbEvent);
          ^
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'WebSocketsClient::WebSocketClientEvent {aka std::function<void(WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int)>}'
```

The data type "WebSocketClientEvent" that is required is specifid in the header file of the library:

**Used Library:**

```
class WebSocketsClient : protected WebSockets {
  public:
    typedef std::function<void(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length)> WebSocketClientEvent;
    void onEvent(WebSocketClientEvent cbEvent);
```

So my question is how do I pass the function in the way required by the library?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my Problem. So apparently there is a difference between normal function and member functions of a class so that pointers to each are also different. A more detailed explanation: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members 
I have now set the function and the variables used inside of it static which solves the problem.